# test module variable set through the environment

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

Lets say that we fave a foo module that sets up a variable based on the environment, as follows:

```py
def get_foo():
    global FOO
    return FOO


def set_foo(val):
    global FOO
    FOO = val


def init_foo():
    import os
    if 'FOO' in os.environ:
        return os.environ['FOO']
    else:
        return 'foo'

try:
    FOO
except NameError:
    FOO = init_foo()
finally:
    print('module foo sets FOO: ', FOO)
```

how can we make a test that deletes the module variable `FOO` and reloads the module to set it properly?

```py
from foo import get_foo
import pytest
import os
import importlib


def test_default():
    assert get_foo() == 'foo'

@pytest.mark.parametrize('value', ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
def test_foo_env_setup(value, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv('FOO', value)
    assert 'FOO' in os.environ
    assert os.environ['FOO']
    import foo
    importlib.reload(foo)
    assert foo.get_foo() == value
```

do I need to setup a context manager somehow with a `mocker`?

Comment: why not setting the environment variables you need in the test environment? I do that all the time.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues the goal is not to set the variable perse but to test the different configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module can be treated as an object, so the FOO attribute can be deleted in the test and do `importlib.reload`.

```py
@pytest.fixture
def foo_mocker():
    import foo
    assert foo.FOO == 'foo'
    del foo.FOO
    yield
    foo.FOO = 'foo'


@pytest.mark.parametrize('value', ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
def test_foo_env_setup(value, monkeypatch, foo_mocker):
    monkeypatch.setenv('FOO', value)
    assert 'FOO' in os.environ
    assert os.environ['FOO']
    import foo
    importlib.reload(foo)
    assert foo.get_foo() == value
```